# Give id to each pod in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is there a way to give each pod in a cluster an id? Like an incrementing integer? How would that look in a yaml configuration? What about giving an id to an already running pod?

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: well what I am looking to do is when I send a request to the load balancer I want to know which pod responds to the request, that's all...each pod has a unique name, but I am not sure if that's available as an ENV var in the container or not.

Comment: The pod's name should be available in each container with the `hostname` command, and as the `HOSTNAME` environment variable.

Comment: You can use `fieldRef` as values to inject pod's metadata. Have a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Answer (score 1):

Look at StatefulSets. StEtefulset deployment add unique ordinal to each instance of the pod